# libgdx smooth movement of rectangles

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics

I want to moove two objects smoothely at Touching.

Here is my Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <96; i++){
    Asstest.rect_pipe_down.y--);
}
```

This should move the rect 96 pixels down (SMOOTH)

But it just close without smoothed...

What did I wrong?

If you Touch, the pipes should close, but not hard, smooth should they close.
But with following code they just close hard...

Here is the full touched code:

```
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = 512 - 320/2;
        Assets.rect_pipe_up.y = -320 + 320/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++){
            smoothTime = TimeUtils.millis();
            if(TimeUtils.millis() - smoothTime > 10) {
                Assets.rect_pipe_down.y--;
                Assets.rect_pipe_up.y++;
                batch.begin();
                    batch.draw(Assets.region_pipe_down, Assets.rect_pipe_down.x, Assets.rect_pipe_down.y);
                    batch.draw(Assets.region_pipe_up, Assets.rect_pipe_up.x, Assets.rect_pipe_up.y);
                batch.end();
            }
        }  
        closed = true;
    }
```

Comment: You have to give us a lot more informations on your game, before anyone can help you. Please try to always give as much information as possible. Tell us also what you have allready tryed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do rendering multiple times in one `render()` call, one call is for drawing exactly one frame. In your current code, the later images simply overwrite the previous ones.

What you could do is have a variable which persists between frames which stores whether or not the pipes are currently closing, a constant for the speed and some condition to tell when they can stop - maybe when they are some given distance from each other, not sure what you would want here. Anyway, that's what I'll use in my example.

Then in the `render()` method, before drawing anything, you can do this:

```
if (closing) {
    Assets.rect_pipe_down.y -= CLOSE_SPEED * delta;
    Assets.rect_pipe_up.y += CLOSE_SPEED * delta;
    if (Assets.rect_pipe_down.y - Assets.rect_pipe_up.y < TARGET_DIST) {
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = Assets.rect_pipe_up.y + TARGET_DIST;
        closing = false;
    }
}
```

Here, `closing` is a variable you set to `true` when you want them to start closing, the others are constants. You could add some more variables/constants if you want to make sure they end up at a specific height independent on framerate.